# Python, unable to find element with class name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

First, i'm an absolute beginner about this, have been trying to locate an element on a web page (lg.telin.co.id/lgnew/cacti.php), this element has the exact name when i wrote the code which is "login_username". However, i got the message " Unable to locate element " until now. Also this web page does not have any id

i used find_element_by_name but nothing work so far

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\BrowserDriver\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get("https://lg.telin.co.id/lgnew/cacti.php")

usernameStr = '123456'

username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/input[@name='login_username']")

username.send_keys(usernameStr)
```

if the code work, text will be filled with characters i assume

Answer (score 1):

Try switch to [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) before handling form input fields:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser.switch_to.frame('cacti')

username = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'login_username')))
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. As the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='cacti']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='login_username']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='cacti']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='login_username']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)